# Click a button to display random information in different text boxes

Tags: c#, user-interface, random, textbox, click

So right now I have a class called "Clans" which list several different clans by name and their respective village.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clan Uchiha = new Clan("Uchiha", "Konoha");
    }
```

And this basically goes on for a couple of more clans. It's defined with two strings, Clan and Village. This is a GUI application, so when I click a button I want it to pick a random "Clan" which will display the Clan and their Village. Mind you I'm a complete newbie when it comes to thinking of projects on my own. I know how to do a click event but I'm not really sure how I make it so the button being clicked outputs information into the Clan and Village text box.

Comment: [list-of-freely-available-programming-books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to do this with the class `Clan` as I don't have this defined. So, I'll use `List<string>` instead if you don't mind but at this point `Clan` must be a collection :)

We'll use `Random` and `List<string>` to sort this out.

First, we must have some items in our collection `List<string>`. Let us create `List<string>` first using the following code

```
List<string> Clans = new List<string>();
```

Then, let's add some items to `Clans`

```
Clans.Add("Uchiha,Konoha");
Clans.Add("Picrofo Groups,Egypt");
Clans.Add("Another Clan,Earth");
Clans.Add("A fourth Clan,Somewhere else");
```

Now, we we'll need to output an item of these when the button is clicked knowing that there's a splitter `,` that splits the first value from the second value in each item. For example. `Uchiha` which is the name of the clan and the first value is separated from `Konoha` which is the location of the clan and the second value by `,` which is the splitter. We'll need to create the Random class as well. Let's try this

```
Random Rand = new Random(); //Create a new Random class
int Index = Rand.Next(0, Clans.Count); //Pick up an item randomly where the minimum index is 0 and the maximum index represents the items count of Clans
string[] Categorizer = Clans[Index].Split(','); //Split the item number (Index) in Clans by ,
MessageBox.Show("Name:" + Categorizer[0] +" | Location: "+ Categorizer[1]); //Output the following
```

Finally, it would look like this in your form class

```
    List<string> Clans = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clans.Add("Uchiha,Konoha");
        Clans.Add("Picrofo Groups,Egypt");
        Clans.Add("Another Clan,Earth");
        Clans.Add("A fourth Clan,Somewhere else");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Random Rand = new Random();
          int Index = Rand.Next(0, Clans.Count);
          string[] Categorizer = Clans[Index].Split(',');
          MessageBox.Show("Name:" + Categorizer[0] +" | Location: "+ Categorizer[1]);
    }
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: It should be: int Index = Rand.Next(0, Clans.Count-1); You need -1 so that you don't get a OutOfBound exception

Comment: @PalR Why? This will avoid an item from `Clans` from being executed. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Say there are 5 items in Clans. If you do Random.next(0, Clans.Count) i.e.Random.Next(0,5), there is a chance 5 will be returned. So Clans[5] will throw an error. Clans[4] is the last object, since the first object is clans[0]

Comment: @PalR I don't think that `[5]` will be evaluated. In `Random.Next`, the maximum value is exclusive and it is not evaluated. `Random.Next(0,5)` will have a chance to evaluate numbers starting from `0` ending at `4` but not 5 as far as I know. For me, the number `5` is never evaluated even if I try it million times :)

Comment: You are correct. From MSDN: A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Comment: @PalR [Here's a summary from this method `Random.Next()` expressing each variable.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AI9Ko.png) Have a great day :)

Comment: From using this method I got the errors as follows:
'System.Windows.Forms.Label' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' could be found

Comment: @DaviDR `System.Windows.Forms.Label`? Perhaps you have tried `label1.Add` instead of `Clans.Add()`? `Label` does not have a method called `Add` and therefore you will receive the error message if you have tried to call the method `Add` from a `Label`.

Comment: Ah, Well I changed it to Clan.Add() which had less errors than having it as Clans. Now that I changed it back it stats: "Form1.Clans is a 'field' but it being used like a 'type'

Comment: @DavidR The class `Clan` which you have defined your self is different from the Generic Collection `List<string> Clans`, It's `Clans` not `Clan`

Comment: @DavidR Can you please post the line you have problems with? Make sure it's `Clans.Add("Something goes here");` and not `Clan.Add("Something goes here");`

Comment: Alright so the problem was a rebuild solution I accidentally did.
Right now I'm having trouble with: The name 'l_clans' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @DavidR Please post the line you are having problems with :)

Comment: int l_randomClanId = l_random.Next(0, l_clans.Count - 1);
            Clan l_randomClan = l_clans[l_randomClanId];//Where l_clans is the Clans object populated

Comment: @DavidR Is `l_clans` representing a Generic Collection? Based on the error you provided, it appears that `l_clans` is not defined at all. To define `l_clans`, please insert the following code under the `public partial class FormName : Form 
{` : `List<string> l_clans = new List<string>();`

Comment: @DavidR I believe that there's something wrong with the code you inserted. Can you please post your code [here](https://gist.github.com/) and post back the link where you have posted your code?

Comment: string[] Categorizer = Clans[Index].Split(','); got the error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Yeah, that was my fault, I accidentally added Pal R's code and it was conflicting with yours.

Comment: @DavidR Thank you. It's looking good so far, I believe that you will not encounter any errors right now. You may remove `List<string> l_clans = new List<string>();` if you won't use it to avoid consuming bytes from memory while executing the application. Have a great day :)

Comment: But it's not working. It says the Index must be non-negative.

Comment: @DavidR You must define `Index` using the following code: `int Index = Rand.Next(0, Clans.Count);`, `Rand` can be defined using the following code: `Random Rand = new Random();`

Comment: @DavidR Also, make sure that you have already added items to `Clans` when the Form loads. `Form1_Load` maps to the event `Load` of your current Form

Comment: Yep, I have that in there and it's coming out wrong.

Comment: @DavidR Did you make sure that this event `Load` of `Form1` is already mapped to `Form1_Load`?

Comment: @DavidR I don't really know what might be causing the problem. Perhaps I will be able to help if you upload your project or provide the codes of Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs. Sorry but I have no idea what could be causing the problem :(

Comment: Idk, I sort of wanted the program to use classes and output the clan and the respective village into two separate text boxes.

https://gist.github.com/3956867

Comment: @DavidR This is also possible! Thank you for posting the code, I'll try my best :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Picrofo EGY! I feel like we're in the home stretch now haha

Comment: @DavidR I was able to solve the problem, turned out that there was a label with the name `Clan` conflicting with the class `Clan`. I've uploaded the files [here](https://gist.github.com/3956942). Have a great day :)

Comment: @DavidR No problems at all, I'm glad I could help. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Clans (List < Clan >) populated already, you can choose a random clan with teh following function:

```
System.Random l_random = new System.Random();
int l_randomClanId = l_random.Next(0, l_clans.Count-1);
Clan l_randomClan = l_clans[l_randomClanId];//Where l_clans is the Clans object populated
```

Now that you have the Random Clan object, you can do the following to populate the textboxes:

```
txtBoxClan.Text = l_randomClan.Clan;
txtBobVillage.Text = l_randomClan.Village;
```

Comment: Oh, I don't have a list at all...I don't think...How do I do that? .__. I only have about a month or two of coding under my belt.

Comment: Check the answer below, on how to create a List. Since you already have a Clan object, you can you  List< Clan >

Comment: Error 4 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need a fast track programming course to understand the basics... It will make your life easier.

Comment: .__. I did take one...The problem is that it was awful and didn't teach anyone anything.